# jQuery AJAX post using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, bootstrap-4

the first "alert" line works, function is working, but second alert line (testing) doesn't work.

```
function atualizarCambioOrcamento(cod, cambio, http){
    alert(http + '/ajax-orcamento-atualizar-cambio.php' + ', ' + cod + ', ' + cambio);

    $.post(http + '/ajax-orcamento-atualizar-cambio.php', {cod:cod,cambio:cambio}, function (data)
    {
        alert('hi, testing');
        if (data.js){
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }, 'json');     
}
```

CONSOLE gives:

> $.post is not a function
>       at atualizarCambioOrcamento (?p=orcamentos:1384)

**ajax-orcamento-atualizar-cambio.php**

```html
<?php
require_once("../connDB.php");

if (isset($_POST['cod'])){
 $cod   = $_POST['cod'];
 $cambio  = $_POST['cambio'];
   
 $update_query = "UPDATE orcamentos SET cambio_praticado='".$cambio."', data_hora=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE cod=".$cod;
 $update_orcamento = mysqli_query($connDB, $update_query);

   $var = Array(
    'js' => 'ok'
   );

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($var);
 exit;

}

?>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser console?  Can you see that the request was sent, and what you got back?

Comment: You should be able to shorten this `{cod:cod,cambio:cambio}` into this: `{cod,cambio}` & like [Archer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023618/archer) says, check the response from the URL in dev-tools >> network. Can you post the code for `ajax-orcamento-atualizar-cambio.php` as well, please?

Comment: It sounds like you have not included jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Hi welcome to stackoverflow.
Make sure that jquery is correctly inserted into your page and that it is imported before your custom javascript file.

Ex:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="your_javascript_file.js" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the slim version of jQuery, which doesn't have AJAX (in my case the $.post() function).